# Bluetoothを使ってssh接続を行えるか?

Tags: macos, windows, ssh

Bluetoothを使ってssh接続をしたいのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか?
WindowsとMacOSの間で接続をしたいです
どちらのコンピュータもホスト、クライアント両方で動かしたいと考えています。
OpenSSHがWindowsをSupportしていない?ようなので
https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases
これを使ってみようと考えています

環境(PC)
OS: Windows 10 Home
Bluetooth PCI-Express Card: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 for Desktop 7260HMWDTX1.R

(Mac)
Mid 2012 MacBook Pro
OS: macOS 10.12.6

ちなみにRaspberry piとMacは可能なようです
あと、Windows Subsystem for Linuxは除きます

Answer (score 1):

手元にWindowsのPCが無いのでとりあえず代わりにAndroid端末で試してみましたが、おそらくいずれにせよRasbery piと同様の方法で可能なようです。

#### Bluetooth PAN を用意する

何れかのPCをホストとして、そちらでPANによるインターネット共有を開きます。手元にはWindowsは無いのですが、macOS
の場合はシステム環境設定の共有から以下のようにインターネット共有を有効化します。
[image]

(Bluetooth PAN が選択できない場合は先にネットワーク環境設定で作成してください)

#### PAN ネットワークに接続する

Windows PC(クライアント側)からPANネットワークに接続してください。おそらく、BTテザリングと同様に接続できるかと思われます。

#### ipアドレスを確認する & 接続

Macをホストとした場合、ネットワーク環境設定には自己割り当てIPとして表示されてしまうようです。(クライアントの場合はIPアドレスが表示されました)
[image]

ここで、Macでターミナルを開き、`ifconfig`コマンドを叩くと`bridge100`のような名前のネットワークが表示されていました。
手元では

> inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255

となっていたので、クライアント側からこのipアドレスに対してssh接続を行ったところ、ログインできました。
ホスト・クライアントともに同様に行えそうです。

#### ところで最近のWindows10にはSSH Server/Clientが入っていた気が

[Windows10 Anniversary updateで追加されたSSH Server Broker/Proxyは、どうやらBash on Ubuntu on Windowsは無関係っぽい | kanonjiのブログ](http://kanonji.info/blog/2017/01/13/ssh-server-broker-proxy-in-windows10-anniversary-update/)

(Homeだと違うかもしれませんね……)

基本的な流れはPoSH SSH,OpenSSH+msys,その他にしろ変わらないはずです。(質問の要点とはそれていたらごめんなさい)

---

参考: Windows 7 において上記同様の手順でクライアントとして接続できました。(逆は省略します)

[image]
アクセスポイント、アドホックネットワーク、どちらを選んでも挙動の違いは確認できませんでしたが、上記のネットワーク共有を有効化せずともアドホックネットワークを選択可能なようです。(ただしこの場合は169.254/16のリンクローカルアドレスになります)

[image]

Comment: 試しにWin7をクライアントにして行おうとするとアクセスポイントが選択できない……スマホをホストにしても同様になってしまう(以前は行けていた気がする)のでなにかおかしいのだろうけど……

Comment: あ、単にドライバの問題のようです、失礼しました